# code working fine on localhost but throwing errors on live server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, .htaccess

I am running a [amazon affiliate](http://funshoppie.com/index.php) website from quite long for multiple locales. Recently India locale stopped displaying products on index page. But other locales are still working fine on live server.

I went to drill down the error & found that India locale is still working perfectly fine on localhost. For a safer side I replaced all scripts once again to ensure it replicates on live server, clear cache etc but result is same.

I have already spent 3 days in identifying error. I have checked error logs its showing errors not related to this problem. htaccess modification also done but no help.

**EDIT**

I think i have found the root cause of problem. This may seem weird once again but curl is the issue here. on localhost everything is working perfectly fine. But on live server, after generating correct signed url, there is no response coming out for India locale. Correctness of signed url information fetched using new browser tab is as follows.

```
<BrowseNodeLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01">
<OperationRequest>
<HTTPHeaders>
<Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"/>
</HTTPHeaders>
<RequestId>c2af6d3b-9a6b-4988-9101-2f324d3860c0</RequestId>
<Arguments>
<Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="MYSECRETPUBLICKEY"/>
<Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="MYLOCALASSOCIATEID"/>
<Argument Name="BrowseNodeId" Value="5311359031"/>
<Argument Name="Operation" Value="BrowseNodeLookup"/>
<Argument Name="ResponseGroup" Value="TopSellers"/>
<Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"/>
<Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2017-08-05T14:15:18Z"/>
<Argument Name="Version" Value="2013-08-01"/>
<Argument Name="Signature" Value="acaYMWI/Moa8twZS2DI4zo/J4sjEE5kXBHsG+z9gqqM="/>
</Arguments>
<RequestProcessingTime>0.010550051</RequestProcessingTime>
</OperationRequest>
<BrowseNodes>
<Request>
<IsValid>True</IsValid>
<BrowseNodeLookupRequest>
<BrowseNodeId>5311359031</BrowseNodeId>
<ResponseGroup>TopSellers</ResponseGroup>
</BrowseNodeLookupRequest>
</Request>
<BrowseNode>
<BrowseNodeId>5311359031</BrowseNodeId>
<Name>Luxury Beauty</Name>
<TopSellers>
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>B01N6O1T8I</ASIN>
<Title>
Forest Essentials Hair Cleanser, Bhringraj and Shikakai, 200ml
</Title>
</TopSeller>
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>B007UPKJ5O</ASIN>
<Title>
Kama Ayurveda Bringadi Intensive Hair Treatment, 100ml
</Title>
</TopSeller>
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>B00803FWR0</ASIN>
<Title>Calvin Klein One Deodorant Body Spray, 152gm</Title>
</TopSeller>
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>B009TOZZ3A</ASIN>
<Title>
Forest Essentials Kashmiri Saffron and Neem Delicate Facial Cleanser, 200ml
</Title>
</TopSeller>
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>B00NXXN10M</ASIN>
<Title>
Kama Ayurveda Nalpamaradi Skin Brightening Treatment, 100ml
</Title>
</TopSeller>
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>B000C1VVQO</ASIN>
<Title>Davidoff Cool Water Woman Deodarant, 100ml</Title>
</TopSeller>
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>B007UPKK3U</ASIN>
<Title>
Kama Ayurveda Pure Rose Water Face and Body Mist, 200ml
</Title>
</TopSeller>
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>B009TP3O6O</ASIN>
<Title>
Forest Essentials Mashobra Honey, Lemon and Rosewater Facial Cleanser, 200ml
</Title>
</TopSeller>
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>B01HIATKS2</ASIN>
<Title>Kama Ayurveda Organic Neem Oil, 200ml</Title>
</TopSeller>
<TopSeller>
<ASIN>B00SUTAE6S</ASIN>
<Title>
Kama Ayurveda Bringadi Intensive Hair Treatment, 250ml
</Title>
</TopSeller>
</TopSellers>
<TopItemSet>
<Type>TopSellers</Type>
<TopItem>
<ASIN>B01N6O1T8I</ASIN>
<Title>
Forest Essentials Hair Cleanser, Bhringraj and Shikakai, 200ml
</Title>
<DetailPageURL>
https://www.amazon.in/Forest-Essentials-Cleanser-Bhringraj-Shikakai/dp/B01N6O1T8I?SubscriptionId=AKIAJVXQJPNIJK243PUA&tag=funshoppiec0e-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01N6O1T8I
</DetailPageURL>
<ProductGroup>Prestige Beauty</ProductGroup>
</TopItem>
<TopItem>
<ASIN>B007UPKJ5O</ASIN>
<Title>
Kama Ayurveda Bringadi Intensive Hair Treatment, 100ml
</Title>
<DetailPageURL>
https://www.amazon.in/Kama-Ayurveda-Bringadi-Intensive-Treatment/dp/B007UPKJ5O?SubscriptionId=AKIAJVXQJPNIJK243PUA&tag=funshoppiec0e-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B007UPKJ5O
</DetailPageURL>
<ProductGroup>Prestige Beauty</ProductGroup>
</TopItem>
<TopItem>
<ASIN>B00803FWR0</ASIN>
<Title>Calvin Klein One Deodorant Body Spray, 152gm</Title>
<DetailPageURL>
https://www.amazon.in/Calvin-Klein-Deodorant-Spray-152gm/dp/B00803FWR0?SubscriptionId=AKIAJVXQJPNIJK243PUA&tag=funshoppiec0e-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00803FWR0
</DetailPageURL>
<ProductGroup>Prestige Beauty</ProductGroup>
</TopItem>
<TopItem>
<ASIN>B009TOZZ3A</ASIN>
<Title>
Forest Essentials Kashmiri Saffron and Neem Delicate Facial Cleanser, 200ml
</Title>
<DetailPageURL>
https://www.amazon.in/Forest-Essentials-Kashmiri-Delicate-Cleanser/dp/B009TOZZ3A?SubscriptionId=AKIAJVXQJPNIJK243PUA&tag=funshoppiec0e-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B009TOZZ3A
</DetailPageURL>
<ProductGroup>Prestige Beauty</ProductGroup>
</TopItem>
<TopItem>
<ASIN>B00NXXN10M</ASIN>
<Title>
Kama Ayurveda Nalpamaradi Skin Brightening Treatment, 100ml
</Title>
<DetailPageURL>
https://www.amazon.in/Kama-Ayurveda-Nalpamaradi-Brightening-Treatment/dp/B00NXXN10M?SubscriptionId=AKIAJVXQJPNIJK243PUA&tag=funshoppiec0e-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00NXXN10M
</DetailPageURL>
<ProductGroup>Prestige Beauty</ProductGroup>
</TopItem>
<TopItem>
<ASIN>B000C1VVQO</ASIN>
<Title>Davidoff Cool Water Woman Deodarant, 100ml</Title>
<DetailPageURL>
https://www.amazon.in/Davidoff-Water-Woman-Deodarant-100ml/dp/B000C1VVQO?SubscriptionId=AKIAJVXQJPNIJK243PUA&tag=funshoppiec0e-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B000C1VVQO
</DetailPageURL>
<ProductGroup>Prestige Beauty</ProductGroup>
</TopItem>
<TopItem>
<ASIN>B007UPKK3U</ASIN>
<Title>
Kama Ayurveda Pure Rose Water Face and Body Mist, 200ml
</Title>
<DetailPageURL>
https://www.amazon.in/Kama-Ayurveda-Pure-Water-200ml/dp/B007UPKK3U?SubscriptionId=AKIAJVXQJPNIJK243PUA&tag=funshoppiec0e-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B007UPKK3U
</DetailPageURL>
<ProductGroup>Prestige Beauty</ProductGroup>
</TopItem>
<TopItem>
<ASIN>B009TP3O6O</ASIN>
<Title>
Forest Essentials Mashobra Honey, Lemon and Rosewater Facial Cleanser, 200ml
</Title>
<DetailPageURL>
https://www.amazon.in/Forest-Essentials-Mashobra-Rosewater-Cleanser/dp/B009TP3O6O?SubscriptionId=AKIAJVXQJPNIJK243PUA&tag=funshoppiec0e-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B009TP3O6O
</DetailPageURL>
<ProductGroup>Prestige Beauty</ProductGroup>
</TopItem>
<TopItem>
<ASIN>B01HIATKS2</ASIN>
<Title>Kama Ayurveda Organic Neem Oil, 200ml</Title>
<DetailPageURL>
https://www.amazon.in/Kama-Ayurveda-Organic-Neem-200ml/dp/B01HIATKS2?SubscriptionId=AKIAJVXQJPNIJK243PUA&tag=funshoppiec0e-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01HIATKS2
</DetailPageURL>
<ProductGroup>Prestige Beauty</ProductGroup>
</TopItem>
<TopItem>
<ASIN>B00SUTAE6S</ASIN>
<Title>
Kama Ayurveda Bringadi Intensive Hair Treatment, 250ml
</Title>
<DetailPageURL>
https://www.amazon.in/Kama-Ayurveda-Bringadi-Intensive-Treatment/dp/B00SUTAE6S?SubscriptionId=AKIAJVXQJPNIJK243PUA&tag=funshoppiec0e-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00SUTAE6S
</DetailPageURL>
<ProductGroup>Prestige Beauty</ProductGroup>
</TopItem>
</TopItemSet>
</BrowseNode>
</BrowseNodes>
</BrowseNodeLookupResponse>
```

**My Curl code**

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: you need to share Deal-details.php, not all of them but specific lines about error.

Comment: Hi Hakan, Deal-details.php error was due to for-loop for retrieved xml, since that xml was not coming out, it was throwing error. I have fixed that part but issue is why index.php code is being redirected to Deal-details.php?

Comment: Remove all the rules rewriting to `Deal-details.php` and retest.

Comment: Nothing changed. read edited part in question pls

Comment: how are you getting that xml ?  is it possible it is too large for your server settings , when getting deals (from/for) india ?

Comment: Set the CA certificate path or file for curl and do not turn off host and peer verification. Those security features are there for a reason.